# YouTube-to-Spotify converter

Tags: javascript, css, converting

I have been doing some JS lately and I would like to get some constructive criticism.

[The project I am working on](https://github.com/Nikamura/YoutubeToSpotify-JavaScript/)

```
var SpotifiedList = [],
youtubeSongs, spotifySongs = 0,
spotifiedSongs = 0,
playNext;

$(document).ready(function () {
  var id = window.location.hash;
  if (id) {
    $("#playlistID").val(id.substring(1));
    startProcess();
  }
});

function resetTimer() {
  console.log("timer reset!")
  clearTimeout(playNext);
}

function startProcess() {
  $("#errorOccured").hide();
  if ($("#playlistID").val().length < 5) { // Checks if there is something entered
    $(".alert-danger").fadeIn().html("Please enter a valid Youtube <b>playlist ID</b>.");
  } else {
    window.location.hash = $("#playlistID").val();
    $("#list").html('<center>This might take some time.</center>');
    $(".alert-info").html("<center>Loading</center>");
    $(".alert-danger").hide();
    retrieveYoutubePlaylist($("#playlistID").val(), 1, [], 1);
  }
}

function retrieveYoutubePlaylist(id, startIndex, list, k) {
  $("#loading").show();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' + id + '?v=2&alt=json&start-index=' + startIndex + '&max-results=50',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (typeof data.feed.entry === 'undefined') {} else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
          if (k == 1) $("#list").html("");
          var title = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
          list.push(title);
          retrieveSpotify(title);
          k++;
        }
        retrieveYoutubePlaylist(id, startIndex + 50, list, k);
        youtubeSongs = list.length;
      }
    },
    error: function (data, a, err) {
      if (err) {
        $(".alert-danger").fadeIn().html("Error Happened: " + err);
      }
    }
  });
}

function retrieveSpotify(title) {
  var url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=' + parseTitle(title);
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    spotifySongs += 1;
    if (data.tracks.length > 0) {
      spotifiedSongs += 1;
      $("#list").append('<li><a href="' + data.tracks[0].href + '" onClick="resetTimer();" title="' + data.tracks[0].artists[0].name + ' - ' + data.tracks[0].name + '">' + data.tracks[0].artists[0].name + ' - ' + data.tracks[0].name + '</a></li>');
      var info = {
        'url': data.tracks[0].href,
        'length': Math.round(data.tracks[0].length * 1000),
        'name': data.tracks[0].artists[0].name + ' - ' + data.tracks[0].name
      }
      SpotifiedList.push(info);
    }
    if (youtubeSongs == spotifySongs) {
      $(".alert-info").html('<div class="btn-group">\
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="play();">\
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> Play/Skip\
        </button>\
        </div><br>Converted songs: <strong>' + spotifiedSongs + '</strong>/' + youtubeSongs);
    }
  });
}

function parseTitle(title) {

  var newTitle = title
  .replace(/[-!$%^&_+|~=`{}:";'<>?,.\/]/g, '')
  .replace(/  /g, ' ')
  .replace(/\[.*\]/g, '')
  .replace(/lyrics/g, '')
  .replace(/\(.*\)/g, '')
  .replace(/\*.*\*/g, '')
  .replace(/   /g, ' ');

  return newTitle;
}

function play() {
  clearTimeout(playNext);
  var song = SpotifiedList[Math.floor((Math.random() * SpotifiedList.length))];
  window.location = song.url;
  x = (song.length / 1000) >> 0;
  seconds = x % 60
  x = (x / 60) >> 0;
  minutes = x % 60;
  console.log('Playing: ' + song.name + ' (' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ')');
  playNext = setTimeout(play, song.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### General

I could work with this code, I only have a few remarks.

**Globals**

You should consider as a minimum to have your 4 globals in an object.

```
var player = 
{
  spotifiedList : [],
  youtubeSongs : 0,
  spotifySongs : 0,
  spotifiedSongs : 0,
  playNext : 0
}
```

You could even add most of the functions to the player object

**resetTimer**

You should remove the `console.log`, which makes this a simple one liner. If you keep it ( function name neatly explains what it does ), make sure to call it from `play()` instead of doing a straight `clearTimeout(playNext)`.

**startProcess**

You could consider caching the jQuery queries, maybe in the before proposed player object.

**retrieveYoutubePlaylist**

`if (typeof data.feed.entry === 'undefined') {} else {` is just wrong.

**retrieveSpotify**

Encoding `onclick=` is wrong as well. 
Building HTML should be contained to separate functions.

**parseTitle**

I have no idea what that does, a few comments are needed there

**play**

I am curious, what does `>> 0` get you ? Force it into an integer?